ZINC15 database: proxy server error when trying to download catalog in any format
I am a complete beginner in the use of such databases.
When navigating to the ZINC15 database website and trying to download an entire catalog with the "Download all as" option the request hangs for a long time and inevitably gives
"Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request
Reason: Error reading from remote server"
no matter the format selected.
Downloading a single substance in whatever format works flawlessly.
Am i missing some crucial part in how one should interact with the ZINC15 database website?
Is there a legit issue with the server?
My internet connection is stable and fast (600Mbps in download).
